# recursive symfony 3.4 complex form embed

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

Having this schema:

[image]

I Would like make a form like that

[image]

I don't know how can I build the form.

- A company haves many persons.
- In a company we have a corporate hierarchy  : employee, boss, subordinate
- A worker can have subordinate worker It's why I have added a recurve link inside company_person for parent child notion link.

The Role is here for saying what is the role of the worker.

**Company**

```
class Company
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyPerson", mappedBy="company")
    */
    private $companypersons;
}
```

**Person**

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyPerson", mappedBy="person",  cascade={"persist"})
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $companypersons;
}
```

**Status**

```
class Status
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyPerson", mappedBy="statut")
     */
    protected $companypersons;

}
```

**CompanyPerson**

```
class CompanyPerson
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateAdded;

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="companypersons", 
        cascade={"persist"})
      */
     private $company;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", 
       inversedBy="companypersons", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $person;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Status",  
       inversedBy="companypersons", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $status;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CompanyPerson", inversedBy="childrens")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyPerson", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $childrens;

    public function __construct(Company $companay= null, Person $person = 
      null, CompanyPerson $parent = null, Status $status = null)
    {
        $this->companay     = $companay;
        $this->person       = $person;
        $this->parent       = $parent;
        $this->status       = $status;
        $this->childrens    = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

I worked on embed form with collections, but I can not create this form, because  it is't very complex for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have rational problems in your mapping. you should use the parent-children pattern inside `Person` , not `CompanyPerson`. a `CompanyPerson` here, is a joint-entity. It is there to persist things like:

- `$dateAdded` : the date at which a relation between a `Company` and a `Person` and an `Status` was stablished.

**Person**

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CompanyPerson", mappedBy="person",  cascade={"persist"})
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $companypersons;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="childrens")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;
}
```

Note to keep `children` without `s`, as it is already in plural form.

Also keep in mind to use `cascade` operations on mapping definition on the inverse side of association. So the

```
class CompanyPerson
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="companypersons", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="companypersons", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $person;
}
```

should be

```
class CompanyPerson
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="companypersons")
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="companypersons")
     */
    private $person;
}
```

## Your Question

To get around the so called, complex form! you may use `mapped=false` setting attribute in your fields. using this, you may tell the symfony that this field, is not mapped to a property of the target entity of your form.

In your case you have `CompanyType` form (with `Company` as target entity) and want to create all those stuff in one go! So you may add unmapped fields to your form and capture theme inside your controller and parse theme as you wish.

Using this method, you should create joint-entities (like Company-Person) by your self (again inside your controller).

Comment: Hi, thank you so mutch, I have readed you answer yesterday but I think beacause I don't have hight level in symfony but this form is a real problem for me I have modified entitys like you said but I'm block on all form type about that and how I can coding that. I feel myself totally zero there :-/

Comment: I have answered your question. Please read it carefully and use Symfony Official Documentation to implement it yourself. If you are after an implementation, no one here in Stack Overflow implements your needs.